# Calling a DLL from VBA

Tags: c++, ms-access, vba, dll

I need to call a DLL function from Access using VBA. The prototype for the DLL function is

```
int __stdcall myFunction(const char* data,
        int rows, int cols, int sl, int fullsize, 
        double aspect_ratio,
        double y,
        void** ppResult);
```

The one I declared in Access:

```
Private Declare Function DllImport_myFunction _
        Lib "myFunctionDLL.dll" _
        Alias "myFunction" _
            (ByVal data As String, _
             ByVal rows As Long, _
             ByVal cols As Long, _
             ByVal sl As Long, _
             ByVal fullsize As Long, _
             ByVal aspectRatio As Double, _
             ByVal y As Double, _
             ByRef handle As Long)
```

When I try to call from Access, Access crashed with an access violation. I placed a breakpoint in the first statement of the DLL function, but it was not hit.

Is the declaration incorrect?

Comment: Is the return type of the declare function also missing in your code? If so try adding "As Long"

Comment: Lucky the signature for the function in the dll has no unsigned members

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the return

```
Private Declare Function DllImport_myFunction Lib "myFunctionDLL.dll" Alias "myFunction" _
(ByVal data As String, _
 ByVal rows As Long, _
 ByVal cols As Long, _
 ByVal sl As Long, _
 ByVal fullsize As Long, _
 ByVal aspectRatio As Double, _
 ByVal y As Double, _
 ByRef handle As Long
) As Long
```

and probably need to add extern "C" to avoid mangling.