# Out of Stack Space error when using CreateObject in Application.OnTime callback

Tags: vba, excel, timer, out-of-memory, autohotkey

I have a very simple example:

```
Private Sub cmd_test_Click()
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"), "finishTimer"
End Sub
```

The callback function is very simple:

```
Public Sub finishTimer()
    Dim AHK As Object
    'code fails on the following line
    Set AHK = CreateObject("AutoHotkey.Script")

    AHK.ahkdll ("")
    Dim ReturnCode As Boolean
    ReturnCode = AHK.ahkExec("Send, {ALTDOWN}3{ALTUP}")

    MsgBox "Complete!"
End Sub
```

However the `CreateObject` line throws an [out of stack space error 28](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264523%28v=vs.60%29.aspx). None of those reasons appear relevant (the call stack only shows the single finishTimer item).

This error is not raised if I simply run `finishTimer` by itself.

What is causing this error with `CreateObject`? How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: not sure I wanna think down the road of garbage collector not "catching" up... What is `AutoHotKey.Script` anyways?

Comment: @mehow http://www.autohotkey.com/ is a sophisticated (yet easy to use) way to override and remap keyboard shortcuts. In this case I am simply using it to send a few keys to move which workspace I am in.

Comment: I am sorry I can't help much here. My guess is that there is an "error/bug" with the AutoHotKey library and not your code. I may be wrong but for now I'll step back and wait maybe [Hans](http://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant) will get to your question.

Comment: Do you just want to send some keys? If that's the case, you could simply use `SendKeys "%3", True`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your problem is getting VBA to recognize the ahk.dll.

I don't think VBA will know what a `autohotkey.script` is unless it has a value in the registered system dlls, which is not usually the case with ahkdll.

[Check out this page](http://benjaminwolfe.tumblr.com/post/411663423/essential-macros-autohotkey-from-vba) where the fellow calls ahk scripts from VBA.

Basically, all you do is to shellexecute authotkey.exe with the script path as a parameter:

```
ShellExecute 0, “open”, “C:\FullPathTo\MyAutoHotKeyScript.ahk”, 0, 0, 1
```

This is a legitimate way to do it unless your VBA package is portable or distributable in which case you want to distribute the ahkdll.dll along with it... in which case you need to find out how to call the dll vrom VBA ([check this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556240/calling-a-dll-from-vba)).

Another idea, if your problem is with running the script on the VBA timer is to run the timer in the ahk script instead.

And if you just want to send key-commands, why not do it with VBS instead of AHK?  It might work better with the timer.  VBS is perfectly capable of sending key-commands.

Comment: Recognizing the ahk.dll is not the problem, because I can run the method by itself fine. Only when it is called via `Application.OnTime` do I have problems (as I stated in the question).

Comment: I have thought about doing the second approach, but creating numerous AHK scripts purely to send a single key command becomes non-maintainable quite quickly,